# functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by inspite of disabling Only_Fukk_Group_By

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have disabled the only_group_by globally and for the user.
[image]

Also made the "stirct => false" in the config/database.php in my Laravel Project.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

My Query that shows error:

```
PayrollSettlement::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b') as `month`"),DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') as `month_no`"))->where('company_id',company_id())->whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b')"))->get();
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume the spelling mistake in the title is just that..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your select clause is including things which don't appear in `GROUP BY` and also are not inside aggregate functions.  Just include both month `DATE_FORMAT` variants and it should work:

```php
PayrollSettlement::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b') AS `month`"), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') AS month_no"))
    ->where('company_id', company_id())
    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b')"), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: The OP knows the problem , the question is how come disabling only_full_group_by does not let me get away with this nonsense. And frankly I'm wondering that too.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am wondering too, and the likely answer is that the functional dependency exclusion only applies to the primary key column or maybe a unique column.  The OP is selecting 2 derived columns.  How does it know that anything else can safely be selected with just one record per derived value?  It can't know this.

Comment: OP is in best position to test your hypothesis, hopefully he will and report results.